# creating URI for media

Tags: java, javafx, uri, media

I'm creating an mp3 player in Java.
I would like to create a URI for Media.
It works only if there is no spaces in the file path, but if there is any spaces, it throws a URISyntaxException.

I have a method in my class that would return a String that represents the URI I've created for the Media. It just doesn't work.

```
private static String convertToFileURL ( String filename )
{
    String path = new File ( filename ).getAbsolutePath ();
    if ( File.separatorChar != '/' )
    {
        path = path.replace ( File.separatorChar, '/' );
    }
    if ( !path.startsWith ( "/" ) )
    {
        path = "/" + path;
    }
    URI uri = URI.create(path).normalize();



    String retVal =  "file://" + uri.toString();

    return retVal;
}
```

Is there any easier way to create a URI for RFC 2396 standards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does

```
File file = new File(filename);
URI uri = file.toURI();
String retVal = uri.toString();
```

do what you need?